# Duplicate, Off-Screen Chart

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to have an off-screen chart that is a duplicate of the displayed version?

I would like to perform some dynamic operations on the chart for exporting purposes (resize, property changes, etc.) but not have those changes visible to the User.

I tried using JS to duplicate the chart, but it appears that the duplicate still links back to the original chart, hence any changes made are still being made to the original, not the off-screen chart.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can set some of this options only for exporting in [exporting.chartOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions).

Comment: I'm in a unique position where I'm unable to use the exporting.chartOptions.  In one example, I need to extract the chart as an SVG, so I've written a JS function that uses .getSVG.

In order to get the exact image size, I resize the chart, then extract the SVG.  The problem is the resizing causes the user to see this.

I was hoping to simply duplicate the chart (off screen) manipulate it, then destroy it.